# How bool variable value can be equals 5?

Tags: c++, debugging

I have a method which accepts the bool variable named `alarm`. I need to access to some array by the index equals to `alarm`:

```
int ind = alarm; // assume here can be only '0' or '1'
```

But sometimes I get `Access violation reading location...` because of my variable equals more than 1 - 3, 5, etc:

[image]

How can this be possible?
...

**Update:**
the problem happens as a result of a randomize memory. I use it to simulate different input data.
Complete verifiable example on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Standard Win32 console application:

```
#include "stdafx.h"        
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void randomize_memory(void* pointer, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t* byteArray = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(pointer);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        byteArray[i] = rand() % 0xff;
    }
}

struct MyStruct 
{
    double  a = 0;
    float   b = 0;
    bool    flag = false;
};

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        MyStruct st;
        randomize_memory(&st, sizeof(st));

        bool tmp = st.flag;
        int ind = tmp;

        if (ind > 1)
            __debugbreak();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The behaviour tested and occurs on compilers *from Visual Studio 2010 (v100) up to Visual Studio 2015 (v140)*.
Looks like I just should not use this way to simulate data, but much worse is that I cannot be sure that some bool variable can be casted to 0-1.

Comment: Where is the code calling this function?

Comment: Don't post images of code - post the code as text.

Comment: And your LimitSwitchSuffix and LimitSwitchColor arrays are correctly initialized?

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The image is important here, but I add the code as text

Comment: By the code calling the function, I meant as well the code where alarm is being initialized...

Comment: You can say: `int ind = (int)(!!alarm)` to force it to 0 or 1. But that will only be hiding the issue (or bug) in your code that is causing `alarm` to have a non-bool value to begin with.

Comment: @Biffen it is impossible here

Comment: Is `status.alarm` equal to `5`? If so, how did it get set to this value?

Comment: What does set_bold do?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code this smells like the kind of error that is unearthed by stricter compilation settings.

Comment: To be clear, you are not getting an access violation because the bool is represented as 5 in memory. Converting a bool to int will always yield `1` or `0`, so assuming your code is designed for that, the shown part should work as intended. It looks a lot like you have a different, unrelated problem somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have undefined behavior somewhere in the code [*that is calling*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.reinterpret.cast#6)  `setAlarmSwitch`.

In C++, an integer value *when converted to* `bool` takes the value `false`/`true`, which when promoted back to an integer type, become `0`/`1`.
But that doesn't mean that `bool` is actually stored or passed in function calls as a single bit. In fact, most ABIs have a minimal width per argument (usually the width of a general-purpose register), and any shorter integral types are *promoted* to it.

To illustrate the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

void printBool(bool x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    printBool(i);
    ((void(*)(int))printBool)(i); // UB
}
```

Will print:

```
1
5
```

The assumption the compiler makes is that a `bool` argument can only contain the values `0`/`1` because if you follow the rules there would never be any other value passed in. It's only possible to pass another value by breaking the rules.
So [then](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.fundamental#footnote-47):

> Using a `bool` value in ways described by this International Standard as “undefined,” such as by examining the value of an uninitialized automatic object, might cause it to behave as if it is neither `true` nor `false`.

---

Your example with `reinterpret_cast` on the other hand is another issue, I believe a bug in MSVC. It is working fine in GCC and clang.

Comment: Could you explain why I shall not use such a `reinterpret_cast` -based operations from point of a global logical correctness view?

Comment: The strict aliasing rule allows any object to be written by `unsigned char`. The cast and write is correct

Comment: @M.M it is correct as long as you're copying from the representation of a valid object of the correct type. Trampling over a `bool` with `5` is definitely not okay.

Comment: @Quentin trampling it is fine if you never read the variable afterwards

Comment: @M.M yeah, well, okay, but... Yeah. You know what I mean. I'll think about it if I need to store a UB-grenade in a `bool` one day :p

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `bool` is an integral type, that means it is possible to implicitly convert `int` or `float` data (for example) to `bool` type. `Zero` value is treated as `false`, and `non-zero` is treated as `true`. For example, the statements-

```
bool a = 0;  // false
bool b = 10; // true
bool c = 3.2; // true
```

If you want your `bool` value (alarm) to be either 0(false) or 1(true), then you may revise the fuinction as below:

```
void StatusParameter::setAlarmSwitch(int ialarm)
{
    bool alarm = (ialarm != 0); // value 5 is converted to 1
    ber_print_func;

    set_bold(alarm);

    int ind = (int)alarm;
    set_suffix(LimitSwitchSuffix[ind]);
    Ber::setElementColor(m_label, LimitSwitchColor[ind]);
}
```

Comment: Even if `bool` is allowed to have multiple truthy representations (which I'm not sure about), there is not much sense in forcing one of them. When convert from `true` to an arithmetic type it has to become `1` regardless of representation.

Answer (score 0):

The *value* of a `bool` can only be `true` or `false`. However the *representation* is implementation-defined.

If you set any variable's memory to something which is not a valid representation for the variable (according to that implementation definition), and you try to read the variable, it causes undefined behaviour which is what you are observing.

You should be able to confirm it by checking the compiler documentation, but the compiler may have said something like "all bits 0 = `false`, all bits 1 = `true`, any other representation invalid".